# Probability of getting a ball and breaking it

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

We have a basket with N balls. k of them are fragile. If we get a fragile ball we have a chance to break it: 0.1. We are getting random ball from the basket q times (after it we don't put the ball back).
1) How to count probability of breaking ball during whole experiment?
2) If we do this experiments several days in a row (each day we change proportion of fragile and not balls) - can we just summarise probabilities of breaking to get total probability for those days?
Thank you

Comment: For the first part, I would calculate the complement event - that is, what is the probability that all of the $q$ balls will reimain unbroken. And for this, I would start with $q=1, 2, 3, \ldots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

If $F$ denotes the number of fragile balls that are chosen then:

$$P\left(\text{all balls unbroken}\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\min\left(k,q\right)}P\left(\text{all balls unbroken}\mid F=i\right)P\left(F=i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\min\left(k,q\right)}0.9^{i}\frac{\binom{k}{i}\binom{N-k}{q-i}}{\binom{N}{q}}$$

so that:

$$P\left(\text{ball breaks during experiment}\right)=1-P\left(\text{all balls unbroken}\right)=1-\sum_{i=0}^{\min\left(k,q\right)}0.9^{i}\frac{\binom{k}{i}\binom{N-k}{q-i}}{\binom{N}{q}}$$

2)

No, because we are not dealing with events that are mutually exclusive. Observe that a summation of these probabilities might well exceed $1$, showing that the summation cannot be a probability.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I got your point about 2), but how can we calculate the total probability for several days of experiments when each day has its own probability of broken ball?

Comment: For each day separately find the probability of no breaks. Multiply them to find the probability of no breaks for several days (so if there are $d$ days then a product of $d$ factors). Then 1 minus this product is the probability of at least one break during the period.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!